# What happened to Luke's hand from The Empire Strikes Back?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, luke-skywalker

Luke apparantly has four hands. There are the two he was born with, a mechanical one he was fitted with at the end of *The Empire Strikes Back*...

[image: Luke's bionic hand in The Empire Strikes Back]

...AND...

> the one we see him fitted with in *The Force Awakens*, both during Rey's force flashback and at the end.  This one looks a lot like the one Anakin was fitted with in *Attack of the Clones*. 
>  [image: Luke's hand in The Force Awakens]

Whatever happened to the third hand?  I know it got a bit damaged in *Retrun of the Jedi*, but it certainly

> looked more natural than the fourth one!  Why not replace the damaged third with another just like it?

Comment: mechanical systems need maintenance and repair.  They wear out too.

Comment: Changed franchise? http://addamsfamily.wikia.com/wiki/Thing

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is unknown if that is the same hand from ESB or not.

Speculation:

> It could be that the prosthetic skin has become removed in events that we have not yet seen.

Comment: That's my assumption - we're led to believe that Luke hasn't exactly been going to see a medical droid for regular repairs for quite some time.

Comment: Counterpoint to the speculation: In Rey's vision, she sees his robotic arm and R2D2. (This shot is seen in the trailers, too.) If this is a vision of something that actually happened, then whatever happened to his arm would have been _before_ he went into hiding. (Or, as a counter-counterpoint, will happen in the future.)

Comment: A vision may be inaccurate with details.